# Can I travel with cremated remains (father's ashes) from Malaysia to India

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, india

we already checked with AirAsia airlines. they need a death certificate and cremation certificate for security purpose. They asked us to check with the customs department of India.

but I'm not sure about India customs

What are the rules and regulations we must follow?

Comment: As the link above explains, all you need to do is to file a form with your nearest Indian consulate/high commission and they will issue you a NOC.